# Parse Email Address in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, email, parsing, substring, charindex

I need help parsing email address in SQL Server 2016

```
email address:
john.doe@co.county.nj.us
john.doe@dnoc.state.gov
john.doe@mail.com
```

I am having difficulties with there are 4 parts to the email address like john.doe@co.county.nj.us.   how do I parse this along with the others examples above?

I don't want to use a split function.

Comment: What are the 4 parts of the email address you want? Why don't you want to use a split function?

Comment: You failed to supply desired results.